# issue in logging error completely while executing system() command in python

Tags: python, error-logging

I am executing a `system()` command and I am trying to log any error message that comes in. The command that I have is:

```
systm = "impala-shell -i " + ip + " -q'compute stats table1'"
    ret = system(systm)
    if ret != 0:
        log = open('log_file.txt', 'a')
        log.write('Error: ' + strerror(ret) + ' \n')
        log.close()
```

The above `systm` command throws an error:

```
Error(2): No such file or directory
Could not execute command: compute stats compute stats table1
```

and I can see this appear on my terminal but when I go to the log file I only see `Unknown error 256` getting written. The whole message that appears on terminal is not getting written in the log file. How can I write the whole message that comes from this error in the log file?

**Note1:** This is for an interview preparation

Comment: Use the subprocess module

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is there no way to achieve this through `system()`. Using `system()` is kind of requirement here with this command

Comment: Why would you not be able to use the subprocess module, check_call will do what you want

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know subprocess is a better way to achieve this but like I said the requirements are forcing me to not use that

Comment: why is it a requirement?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am preparing for an interview and recently one of my friend was asked to solve this question. The interviewer had specifically asked to use system() and not any other way

Comment: So `"impala-shell -i " + ip` would start a shell?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham its a impala shell command. This will start a impala shell on which the query will be executed

Comment: Sorry missed the second part of your question, this is trivial to solve depending on what you are allowed to change

Comment: Can you just add a `2>log_file.txt` to the command?

Comment: Does the output have to also appear on the screen?

Comment: @ap The command cannot be modified from what my friend had told me so I dont think we can add anything to it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the error output should come in the file as it comes on the screen.

Comment: I mean is `systm = "impala -i " + ip + " -q'compute stats table1' 2>> log_file.txt"` sufficient? Or do you have to output it to the shell also?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I dont know the exact details but I assume it has to be on both - the file as well as shell? What is `2>>` doing in above command?

Comment: it is appending stderr to the logfile, if the command is successful it won't add anything to the file once the process does not write to stderr instead of stdout. Are you certain the answer to the question is not to use subprocess, was that stipulated to your friend?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it was stipulated to my friend that he can only use system() and no other way to get this. Like I have mentioned that when the error comes then in log file only a single line is written while on the screen I can see details about the error

Comment: You are seeing the output from the os.system call, there is no way to get that from os.system.